# Batch script to create a string from directory

Tags: batch-file, directory

I have a script that is looking for a filetype and then finding a string in the directories.

```
dir /a-d /b /s *.file.filetype | findstr /v /i "string"
```

As a result I get dozens of directory paths that contain the string

```
C:\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5\dir6\file1
C:\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5\dir6\file2

...
...
...
```

How do I create a string from what dir4 is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to get dir name 4 levels deep:

```
FOR /F "DELIMS=\ TOKENS=5" %%d IN ('dir /a-d /b /s *.file.filetype ^| findstr /v /i "string"') DO SET "dir4=%%d"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=" %%S in ('dir /a-d /b /s *.file.filetype^| findstr /v /i "string"^|findstr /i "\\dir4\\"') do set "_string=%%~S"
```

Comment: for safety reason you can use `|findstr /i "\\dir4\\"`